# Find Files in Multiple Subdirectories but with the same parent folder name & extension

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find all `*.nupkg` files located in parent folder called `bin`

So far I've only managed to get 2 queries that find different levels of `bin` folders but I'm wanting to have a query that combines both. I'm sure its possible with wildcards I just couldn't get it right.

This which finds these items

```
foreach ($_ in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\agent\_work\**\bin\*.nupkg" -Recurse ))
{
  Write-Host $_.fullname
  #remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse 
}

C:\agent\_work\3\s\ProjectA\bin\Release\ProjectA.4.2.6.29.nupkg
C:\agent\_work\3\s\ProjectA\bin\Release\ProjectA.4.2.6.30.nupkg
C:\agent\_work\3\s\ProjectA\bin\Release\ProjectA.4.2.6.31.nupkg
```

And this which finds these items

```
foreach ($_ in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\agent\_work\3\s\*\*\bin\*.nupkg" -Recurse ))
{
  Write-Host $_.fullname
  #remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse 
}

C:\agent\_work\3\s\ProjectB\SubProjectA\bin\SubProjectA.4.2.6.26.nupkg
C:\agent\_work\3\s\ProjectB\SubProjectA\bin\SubProjectA.4.2.6.31.nupkg
C:\agent\_work\3\s\ProjectB\SubProjectA\bin\SubProjectA.4.2.8.3.nupkg
C:\agent\_work\3\s\ProjectB\SubProjectA\bin\SubProjectA.4.2.8.4.nupkg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a different approach, start from a given parent directory and find all directories recursively below it named `bin`.

For each of these bin directories delete all `*.nupkg` files.

I never use wildcards in the -Path parameter.